# query failed (JSInterpreterFailure) ReferenceError Buffer is not defined in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert **base64** to **string** in mongo DB with new operator `$function`
here is the MongoDB playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/AWMgsv8tbir

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "ecnrypted": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(key) { var b = new Buffer(key, 'base64'); return b.toString()}",
          "args": [
            "$key"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

what i got is:

```
query failed: (JSInterpreterFailure) ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined :
```

have anyone query value base64 to string in mongo?

Comment: Even I'm trying to use external functions inside $function body. I'm getting the same error. Did you get the solution for this?